# cannot import name 'GraphSparqlQAChain' from 'langchain.chains'

Tags: langchain

I am trying to create a route in django but getting this issue : cannot import name 'GraphSparqlQAChain' from 'langchain.chains'

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.chains import GraphSparqlQAChain
from langchain.graphs import RdfGraph


def respond_to_question(request, question):
    """Responds to the user's question by using the GraphSparqlQAChain model."""
    graph = RdfGraph(
        source_file="./test.ttl",
        standard="rdf",
        local_copy="test.ttl",
    )
    chain = GraphSparqlQAChain.from_llm(
        ChatOpenAI(temperature=0), graph=graph, verbose=True
    )
    answer = chain.run(question)
    return JsonResponse({
        "answer": answer,
        "direction": "incoming",
        "sender": "ChatGPT"
    })
```